# Count data in stored procedure mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

We have a system containing a school protocol where we want to be able to insert a class and the subject of the class and then be able to see an overview af all the students attendance of this specific subject in the specific class.

I tried to create a stored procedure with no luck.

Our data tables looks like the following:
[image: AttendanceLog]

We would like to make it so when you give 2 values (keaclass_is and subject_id) in the Stored Procedure you will get back a view of how many times a username_fk has been attending a subject out of all the possible occurrences with the same keaclass_id. Therefore we need to check the amount of occurrences the subject has had on the date too.

As an example we want the outcome to look like the following:

[image: View outcome]

So Nadi6548 has been attending subject_id 2, 4 out of 4 possible occurrence and nico4108 has only been attenting subject_id 2, 1 out of 4 possible occurrence.

Comment: 1. Why stored procedure and no a simple query with parameters? 2. Pls share what you have tried as the question reads as gimme the codez without it.

Comment: Work out the query you need to retrieve this information. Once you have a working query, then and only then create the stored procedure. Why? Stored procedures are messy to debug.